# Datamapper update enum

Tags: ruby, enums, datamapper

My model looks like this:

```
class Project
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property    :id, Serial
    property    :title, String
    property    :slug,  String
    property    :status, Enum[:open, :closed ], :default => :open
    has n, :issues
end
```

How do I use Project.update() to change the status of the enum to closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like that:

```
Project.update(:status => :closed)
```